# Get current user middleware from JWT using express

Tags: javascript, express.js, oauth, jwt

I'm using Sequelize and Google oAuth for authentication, I want to create a middleware that

1. Verifies the sent token passed in the headers matches the  one the user was initially signed to.
2. Finds the user if he/she exists and returns it to the client.

The middleware be used for protected routes.

```js
const getCurrentUser = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.headers || !req.headers.authorization) return res.status(401).end();

  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  if (!token) return res.status(401).end();

  JWT.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(401).end();
    } else {
      res.locals.JWT = decoded;
      const user = await models.user.findOne({ where: { id: decoded.id } });
      if (!user) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'No user found' });
      req.user = user;
      next();
    }
  });
};
```

One thing I'd like to make sure I'm doing correctly is error handling. Does this look alright? Anything to change/improve on?